# matplotlib plot X Y Z data from csv as pcolormesh

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have data in a csv of this form:

```
X,Y,Z
0,0,0.0
0,1,0.0
1,0,1.0
1,1,0.55
2,0,4.0
2,1,3.216
```

I am not sure how to feed this data to `pcolormesh`. I think I have to use `np.meshgrid` but I'm not sure how to in this case.

```
dat = pd.read_csv('my_dat.csv')
plt.pcolormesh(dat['X'], dat['Y'], dat['Z'])
plt.show()
```

Results in `Value error: need more than one value to unpack`

I don't understand - why doesn't this just work?

Comment: How do you want to plot this data ? When using `pcolormesh(x,y,c)`, x and y are coordinates of cells, and c is a 2D array for the values inside the cells. It does not seem compatible with your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data just needs to be reshaped. No need to use `np.meshgrid` here, since you already have an x and y coord for each cell.

If you have `nx` coordinates in x, and `ny` coordinates in y, then you can do this:

```
X = dat['X'].reshape(nx,ny).T
Y = dat['Y'].reshape(nx,ny).T
Z = dat['Z'].reshape(nx,ny).T

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

Note that pcolormesh prefers that you have your `x` and `y` dimensions be one greater that the `z` dimension, since `x` and `y` define the edges of the cells, and `z` defines the colour at the cell centre. From the docs:

> Ideally the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C; if the dimensions are the same, then the last row and column of C will be ignored.

So, in you example, the colours from the final row and column will be lost, unless you add a row and column of dummy cells with x and y coordinates 1 greater than your number of cells. An alternative might be to use [`plt.contourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf), for which x, y, and z should be the same length.

Comment: Does this require that the x,y data is structured on a regular grid? Or can the answer be adapted if x and y are randomly sampled points.

Comment: pcolormesh requires a regular grid.

Comment: thank-you @tmdavison . I guess that for unstructured points the first step then is to interpolate onto a regular grid.

Comment: What is `nx` and `ny`? Using `nx = x.size; ny = y.size` return `cannot reshape array of size nx into shape (nx,ny)`.